# Am I interpretting this interaction term correctly?

Tags: least-squares, interaction, treatment

I am running a model with an interaction term and I am unsure of the interpretation even after reading the other questions here in the forum.

My model looks as follows:
[image]

Where roi is the return on investment, logfreq is the log transformed trading frequency and treated is the binary treatment variable.

My interpretation of the interaction:

The interaction term is negative implying that being treated leads to lower trading frequency.

Is this the correct interpretation? Any hint would be much appreciated, and I hope this does not seem too trivial.

Comment: Before you interpret anything, you should look at whether this model is a good fit for your data. Plotting the model (which in effect is two lines as explained by @frank) on top of the data might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know for sure how `treated` interacts with `logfreq` until we investigate that specifically.
The current results may mean that if the relationship as linear as assumed (this is very unlikely), `treated` has a constant effect on `roi` when present, while `logfreq` has a linear relationship with `roi` with the coefficient `0.35369` only when `treated` is absent. When `treated` is present the linear effect of `logfreq` on `roi` is `0.35369-0.30848=0.04521`, which may even be statistically non-significant.

Answer (score 6):

You have two linear equations for `roi` as a function of `logfreq`, one for no treatment and one with treatment. To decide which one results in a larger `roi`, we have to know what range your `logfreq` values are in. In the code below, `roi1` is the ROI in the treated case:

```
> logfreq <- seq(0, 10, .1)
> roi <- 0.11147 + 0.35369*logfreq
> roi1 <- 0.11147 + 0.35369*logfreq + 0.84900 -0.30848*logfreq
> plot(logfreq, roi, type = 'l', col = 'seagreen', panel.first = grid())
> lines(logfreq, roi1, col="steelblue")
```

[image]

Here, the blue line is with treatment. Thus, if your values of `logfreq` are below $\approx 3$, `treated` will have a positive effect on `roi`, but above three, it will have a negative effect. Note, that this is independent of the value of the nonsignificant intercept.

More professional visualization of interactions can be achieved e.g. with the [`interactions`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/interactions/vignettes/interactions.html) R-package.